# can not compile cratedb correctly

Tags: cratedb

i download the source of cratedb,  but can not compile correctly,here is the detail:
jdk:1.8

/workspace/crate$ ./*gradlew  compileJava*

```
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:es:es-core:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:es:es-core:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:es:es-core:classes UP-TO-DATE
:es:es-core:jar UP-TO-DATE
:core:compileJava
/workspace/crate/core/src/main/java/io/crate/action/FutureActionListener.java:26: error: package org.elasticsearch.action is not available
import org.elasticsearch.action.ActionListener;
```

it should be the elasticsearch package missing, how could i can do next?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please follow the instructions on https://github.com/crate/crate/blob/master/DEVELOP.rst - i think you were missing the `--recursive` when cloning the repository and there for the es submodule wasn't pulled it.

Comment: i cloned it in idea, so it does  missing the --recursive.  thanks a lot!